# The differentiation of the trace of complex matrix

Tags: matrices, random-matrices

Condition: *all the matrices are complex*. $\dagger$ denotes the conjugate transpose, $*$ denotes the conjugate, $\mathop{Trace}$ denote the trace of a matrix. What is the differentiations of the following Lagrangian function respect to $X^*$:
$L(X,\lambda) = \mathop{Trace}(XH)+\lambda \mathop{Trace}(X^{\dagger}X)$

Comment: This is a great document to have. http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf It should help you answer your question.

Comment: Thanks mtiano. I have read the document. But I get a different result from the proof of a lemma in the appendix of one acdemic paper. The result I get is $\lambda X$, but the result in the paper  is $H^{\dagger}+ \lambda X$. What's worong with my computation?

Comment: Actually. this document is useful.[link](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MN_Numerical%20methods/MNw_Wavelets,%20signal%20processing/Hjorungnes%20A.%20Complex-valued%20matrix%20derivatives..%20With%20applications%20in%20signal%20processing%20(CUP,%202011)(ISBN%200521192641)(O)(271s)_MNw_.pdf). But I get a different result, why?

Comment: So $\lambda X$ comes from the derivative of $\lambda Tr(X^{\dagger}X$ which you seem to understand ( I don't) and $H^{\dagger}$ seems to comes from the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial X} Tr(XH) = H^T$. That's my guess.

Comment: According to the [book](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MN_Numerical%20methods/MNw_Wavelets,%20signal%20processing/Hjorungnes%20A.%20Complex-valued%20matrix%20derivatives..%20With%20applications%20in%20signal%20processing%20(CUP,%202011)(ISBN%200521192641)(O)(271s)_MNw_.pdf) .  $\ \displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}~ \mathrm{trace} (AX)}{\mathrm{d}X^*}=0.\quad$

Answer (score 0):

Using the properties of the trace and Frobenius product, $dTr(XH)=dTr(HX)=d(H^T:X)=H^T:dX$, so $\frac{d}{dX}Tr(XH)=H^T$. Similarly, the second term is $dTr(X^{\dagger}X)=d(X^*:X)=X^*:dX$ so that  $\frac{d}{dX}Tr(X^{\dagger}X)=X^*$.

Similarly, you have $\frac{d}{dX^*}Tr(XH)=0$ and for the second term using the properties of Frobenius product: $dTr(X^{\dagger}X)=dTr(XX^{\dagger})=d(X^T:X^{\dagger})=X^T:(dX^*)^T=X:dX^*$ so that  $\frac{d}{dX^*}Tr(X^{\dagger}X)=X$.

Note, that if $\lambda$ is a scalar, this is not a proper Lagrangian, as $X^{\dagger}X$ is a set of constraints, thus $\lambda$ should be a matrix. You may want to read "Mathematical Methods and Algorithms for Signal Processing by Todd K. Moon, Sec. 18.7".