# Questions about the Frobenius inner product of complex matrix and the derived Gradients.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a function $f:\mathbb{C}^{n\times p} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; X\mapsto \mathrm{tr}(XX^{H})$, where $H$ denotes the Hermitian transpose.
And I would like to compute the gradient of $f$ with respect to $X$, according to
$$\mathrm{d}f v = \left<\nabla f(X), v\right>, \hspace{1cm} v=\mathrm{d}X$$

1. My first question is : what is the definition of Frobenius inner product for $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times p}$?
   [The wikipedia gives the following definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product):
   \begin{equation}
   \left<X,X\right> = \mathrm{tr}(X^{H}X) \tag{1}
   \end{equation}
   But in many answers, such as [The differentiation of the trace of complex matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552283/the-differentiation-of-the-trace-of-complex-matrix), the Frobenius inner product seems to be considered as $$\left<X,X\right> = \mathrm{tr}(X^{T}X) \tag{2} $$
   where $T$ denotes the tranpose only, not the Hermitian transpose.

I would like to know, for my funtion $f$, which definition I should use?

2. My second question is: what is the gradient of function $f$, in the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), equation (248), the gradient of $f$ is $2X$, but is many answers, gradient of $f$ is $X^{*}$, such as [Matrix trace derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060542/matrix-trace-derivatives?rq=1), and [The differentiation of the trace of complex matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552283/the-differentiation-of-the-trace-of-complex-matrix).

Looking forward to your answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Wirtinger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) sense, $X$ and $X^*$ are treated as independent variables and their gradients are calculated separately
$$\eqalign{
 &\;\;f = X:X^* \\
&df = X:dX^* \;+\; X^*:dX \\
&\boxed{\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial X^*} = X \quad\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = X^*\;\,\\}\\
}$$
However, if $\,X^*=X\;$ then there is only **one** independent variable and thus one gradient
$$\eqalign{
&df = X:dX \;+\; X:dX \\
&\quad\;\; = 2X:dX \\
&\boxed{\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = 2X\;\,\\}\\
}$$